# Create an SSL key which signed by CA in CentOS

Tags: ssl, centos, ansible, keytool

I'm trying to create an SSL key for Kafka broker as mentioned [here](http://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html). I use Ansible & docker.

The problem is that I can’t automate it - keytool is not part of CentOS, so I can’t create it for each broker.

Is there any playbook for Ansible which creates a key and signs it with CA that works on CentOS?

Comment: There is no such thing as an 'SSL key signed by a CA'. Do you mean SSL *certificate*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the keytool command, you need to install Java. Keytool is part of Java package. A simple:

```
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk
```

Will help you to have it.